# Excel, transfering data from one cell to another

Tags: excel-formula

I am having so much trouble trying to find my answer that I thought I would ask my question here.

In one column (column A) I have names of girls and in another column (column C) I enter the pay for each girl.  Further down my sheet I have each girl's name per column, on the same line, and I want to have the pay to be copied under each girl's name.

For example when I enter in cell C4 the number 5, I would like this number to be copied to cell E4 automatically, so that I only have to enter it once.  See the attached image:
[image]

The data from cell C5 should be copied to cell F4.  I am having trouble using the VLOOKUP since each girl's name will be in the column A more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **E4** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$8,SMALL(IF($A$4:$A$8=E$3,ROW($A$4:$A$8)),ROWS($2:2))-1),"")
```

Copy both downward and across:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in E4 then filling both right and down.

```
=iferror(index($c:$c, aggregate(15, 6, row($4:$999)/($a$4:$a$999=e$3), row(1:1))), text(,))
```

[image]